# What is happened with QSocketNotifier when file descriptor becomes bad?

Tags: c++, qt, hardware, file-descriptor

Assuming I have `QSocketNotifier` that is constructed against valid file descriptor (it's actually joystick device - `/dev/input/js0`). I connect `QSocketNotifier::activated` with corresponding handler. When file disappears (hardware is disconnected) - what should I expect?

As I can see, `::activated` emits repeatedely with the same socket parameter, but there is `errno == ENODEV` after `read()` call inside handler. May I expect that `::activated` would be *always* emitted after descriptor goes bad (and therefore catch disconnection event) or actual behavior of `QSocketNotifier` is not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to the behavior of `/dev/input/js0` in particular since I've never used that device, but the general behavior for a socket/file-descriptor whose remote-connection has closed would be to return as ready-for-read, and then when the application tries to call `recv()` (or `read()`) on the file descriptor, either of these calls would return 0 (a.k.a. EOF) to indicate that the remote device has closed the connection.

Presumably this (or something similar) is happens when using `QSocketNotifier` as well, i.e. Qt's internal code will notify the `QSocketNotifier` that the file descriptor is now ready-for-read, and the `QSocketNotifier` will respond by emitting the `activated(int)` Qt-signal.  So I think your use-pattern is good.

(What *would* be bad/undefined behavior is if you (or somebody else) called `close()` on the file descriptor without first disabling or destroying any `QSocketNotifier` objects that were watching that file-descriptor.  That would be bad because the `QSocketNotifier` object(s) would have no way to know that the file descriptor was closed, and so they'd keep trying to use it -- probably they would get `EBADFS`-type errors when they did so, but there's also a chance that some other thread in your process would create a new file descriptor shortly afterwards for some unrelated purpose, and by chance it would end up with the same int-value as the one that was previously `close()`'d, and then you'd have a really fun time debugging the odd behavior that resulted :))